# How to solve AX=B for some given 3x3-matrix A and 3-vector B

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I want to solve the following equation
$$AX=\left( \begin{matrix}
   9  \\
   3  \\
   -3  \\
\end{matrix} \right)
$$

where 
$$A=\left( \begin{matrix}
   1 & -2 & -2  \\
   -2 & 1 & -2  \\
   -2 & -2 & 1  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$$

How can I do this? I know the first step is to calculate the inverse of $A$.

Comment: @Behrouz Maleki Thank you for your markdown improvement :)

Comment: $A^{-1}AX=A^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
         9 \\
         3 \\
         -3\\
     
        \end{bmatrix}$=>$X=A^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
         9 \\
         3 \\
         -3\\
     
        \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @juliogodoy So the answer is the product of inverse A and (9,3,-3)?

Comment: yes, you right, that are the result

Comment: but, wait a minute, that is true if and only if A has inverse

Comment: Okey, thank you for your clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of solving this problem. One way is to reduce the matrix A to [reduced echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form). If you do the same for the vector [9, 3, -3] then you can easily read the solution of.

Other way is indeed to calculate the inverse of A. Then we can multiply both sides of the equation with $A^{-1}$ and you will see that the lhs reads $IX$ or just $X$. Note that in this case the unity matrix I is the reduced echelon form.

You can always obtain the inverse matrix (if it exists) by putting matrix A next to I and reducing A to echelon while doing the same type reduction steps on I.

Comment: I know how to get the inverse form of a matrix so that's great :)